# Variable value change for no reason when using cupy

Tags: python, machine-learning, gradient, cupy

I am implementing a gradient formula for machine learning with cupy. However I went into a strange bug where the variable temp_value change for no reason.
Here is my code:

```
import cupy as cp
def gradient_1d(f, x):
    grad = cp.zeros_like(x)
    h = 0.00001
    for index in range(x.size):
        temp_value = x[index]
        print(temp_value,'1')
        x[index] = float(temp_value) + h
        print(temp_value,'2')
        plus_result = f(x)
        print(temp_value,'3')
        x[index] = temp_value - h
        print(temp_value,'4')
        minus_result = f(x)
        print(temp_value,'5')
        grad[index] = ((plus_result - minus_result)/2*h)
        print(temp_value,'6')
        x[index] = temp_value
    return grad


def f2(x):
    if x.ndim == 1:
        return cp.sum(x**2)
    else:
        return cp.sum(x**2, axis=1)


def main():
    x = cp.array([1, 2])
    grad = gradient_2d(f2, x)
    print(grad)


main()
```

The out put is:

```
1 1
1 2
1 3
0 4
0 5
0 6
2 1
2 2
2 3
1 4
1 5
1 6
[0 0]
```

You can observe that the value of temp_value decreases by one each time it hits the 4th check point but I did nothing that update this variable.

Why???
Thanks for you help in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is probably because `temp` is assigned to `x[index]` but `x[index]` gets changed. Use `temp_value = x[index].copy()` instead of `temp_value = x[index]` as first statement in the for-loop. For this, you also need to add `import copy` at the top of the file.

Comment: Or do what you did in a different line already: `float(x[index])` will create a copy as well.

Comment: Thank you so much!